# mysql_real_escape_string not echoing variable

Tags: php, sanitize

I'm trying to sanitize a variable and am having an issue.

This code outputs the echo correctly:

```
$to_raw = $_POST['to'] ;
echo $to_raw;
```

But this returns nothing:

```
$to_raw = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['to']) ;
echo $to_raw;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` only works if you're connected to a database (it should throw a warning if you're not).  Did you call `mysql_connect`?

Comment: Aw, so this line needs to go below the mysql_connect? I have a connection, but it's lower in the code.

Comment: Yeah, you need to connect to the database before calling any other `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't work if you haven't called `mysql_connect`. Better workaround would be creating a MySQL connection on the **top**, before calling the `mysql_real_escape_string`.

```
mysql_connect("localhost");
$to_raw = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['to']) ;
echo $to_raw;
```

#### Suggestion

It is better to use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*` functions compared to `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated.